# Why is the lack of sound proof theory fatal for Second-Order Logic but the practical lack of sound proof theory for FOL benign?

Tags: philosophy-of-logic, computation, complexity

Received orthodoxy says, among the community of logicians, that first-order logic (with predicates, connectives, and variables) is good because it has a sound proof theory and second-order logic (with predicates, connectives, variables, and quantifiers over predicates) is no good because it lacks a sound proof theory.

However, last time I checked, the fastest-known algorithm for the ostensibly sound proof theory for first-order logic has a best-case running time of something like $e^(e^x)$ meaning that it is so fast-growing that no human intelligence can use it, meaning that for human beings, first-order logic has no practical sound proof theory any more than second-order logic does.

Seeing that, why all the disparaging of second-order logic when it's no worse than first-order logic?

Comment: "sound" means "deriving true conclusion from tre premises. Also SOL is sound; see [SOL](https://plato.stanford.edu/Entries/logic-higher-order/)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA According to W. V. O. Quine, SOL doesn't have an algorithm to check whether a proof in SOL is sound or not.

Comment: You probably mean that second-order logic with standard semantics does not have a proof system that is simultaneously [sound, complete and effective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Metalogical_results). This did not prove "fatal", and SOL with Henkin semantics does have it. And generally, these sorts of results are used for conceptual analysis of logical systems, whether proof procedures are practically feasible or not is mostly moot, except, maybe, to some finitists.

Comment: Are we talking about (sound proof) theory, or sound (proof theory)? Also, what do you mean when you say *"fastest-known algorithm for the ostensibly sound proof theory"*? An algorithm usually solves a problem; I don't know what you mean when you talk about an algorithm "for a theory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sound" in logic has a precise meaning; see e.g. Ethan Jerzak, [Second Order Logic](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Jerzak.pdf): page 6:

> **Theorem 3.1**. *Soundness* of the deductive system for FOL: If **Γ ⊢ Φ**, then **Γ ⊨ Φ**, that means thatall the logical axioms are valid and that both *Modus Ponens* and [the rules for quantifiers] preserve logical implication.

And page 7:

> **Theorem 3.3**. *Completeness* of FOL (Gödel 1930): If **Γ ⊨ Φ** then **Γ ⊢ Φ**.
> Proof. This proof is by no means straightforward. It depends crucially on a prin-
> cipal of innity (namely, that models with infinite domains exist).

Page 12: "The completeness theorem for first-order logic suggests, intuitively speaking,that we have developed the "right" semantics and the "right" deductive system for a system with quantifiers and variables that can range over objects. As we will show, for second-order logic, there can be no such match, no matter what semantics and deductive system we use.

See page 15:

> **Theorem 6.1**. *Soundness* of the deductive system for SOL: Let **Γ** be a set of formulas and **Φ** a single formula in L2K. If If **Γ ⊢(D2) Φ**, then **Γ ⊨ Φ** in the standard semantics. Like the soundness proof for FIOL, this proof is relatively straightforward [checking] every axiom and rule of inference.

*BUT*... page 16:

> The natural thing to inquire now is whether the deductive system for SOL, like that for FOL, is complete. **The answer will be negative**, by Gödel's [First Incompleteness Theorem](https://plato.stanford.edu/Entries/goedel-incompleteness/).

And page 18: "**Theorem 6.3**. The standard semantics for SOL is not *compact*." And finally: "*Theorem 6.4*. Let **D** be any efefctive deductive system that is sound for SOL. Then **D** is not complete: there is a logical truth that is not a theorem of **D**."

*Note*: the fact that FOL is *sound* and *compolete* DOES NOT mean that it is [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)):

> A logical system is *decidable* if there is an effective method for determining whether arbitrary formulas are theorems of the logical system. For example, propositional logic is decidable, because the truth-table method can be used to determine whether an arbitrary propositional formula is logically valid.

> *First-order logic is not decidable in general*; in particular, the set of logical validities in any signature that includes equality and at least one other predicate with two or more arguments is not decidable. Logical systems extending first-order logic, such as second-order logic and type theory, are also undecidable.

For more details, see [Second-order and Higher-order Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/Entries/logic-higher-order/).

For a useful discussion of Quine's point of view regarding SOL, see George Boolos, [On Second-Order Logic (The Journal of Philosophy, Volume 72, Issue 16, 1975)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2025179).